# Web Request Encoding Problem

Tags: asp.net, character-encoding, httpwebrequest

Hi i'm getting encoding problems with the code below any ideas?

```
string url = "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=istanbul,TR&hl=tr";
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string retVal = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Response.Write(retVal);
        }
```

My Screenshoot is like that;

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Got the same problem with spanish. The accepted answer worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google is notorious for checking the `useragent` HTTP header. Because you're not setting it its encoding everything as `ISO-8859-9`. The simple solution is to manually set the `UserAgent` property of the `HttpWebRequest`. Set it to anything you want, below is a Firefox string (and an extra `Using` block):

```
        string url = "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=istanbul,TR&hl=tr";
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1";
        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string retVal = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(retVal);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Let me buy you a beer sometime.