# Is it possible to get data from web response in a right encoding

Tags: c#, .net, encoding

```
using (WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse())
{       
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string tmpStreamData = string.Empty;        
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            while (reader.Peek() > -1)
            {                   
                tmpStreamData += (char)reader.Read();
            }               
        }
        MessageBox.Show(tmpStreamData);
    }
}
```

Sometimes I get � symbols in the "tmpStreamData". Is it possible to avoid such situations and get data in the readable format?

Comment: Where are you getting the response data from?  If it's from a server you've got control of you can ensure that the encoding is the same on both sides.

Comment: I think you probably need to explicitly set the `UserAgent` property on the `HttpWebRequest` object... The accepted answer on this question should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031222/web-request-encoding-problem

Comment: No. I do not control server-side. I get data from the pages, that sometimes return data in russian language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Get HTTP response. If this is not an HTTP response, you need to know the encoding yourself.
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse()) 
{
    // If not an HTTP response, then response.CharacterSet must be replaced by a predefined encoding, e.g. UTF-8.
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet))) 
    {
        // Read whole stream to string.
        string tmpStreamData = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
        MessageBox.Show(tmpStreamData);
    }
}
```

Comment: But there is not the "StreamReader" constructor, that takes "Encoding" like "String" type.

Comment: When I try to find out encoding in this way: Encoding.GetEncoding(response.ContentEncoding). It throws exception, that says "incorrect encoding name".

Comment: You should make sure `responce` becomes `response`.